# What is the name of the following phenomenon: a good estimate of how much longer something will last, is how long it has already lasted?

Tags: survival, inference, descriptive-statistics

I read the following anecdote, but I can no longer find any references to it online.

A group of stand-up comedians were at a diner discussing how long their careers would last. They concluded that the best way to estimate this is by looking at how long their careers had *already* lasted. i.e., if you've been famous for 5 years, you in expectation have 5 more years of fame left.

I believe that this phenomenon is named after the diner in which this discussion took place, but I can't find any references online. Does anyone know the name (either the colloquial name, or a more technical model to describe the phenomenon)?

Comment: well I know nothing about that theory, but you might find this one interesting: http://www.acu.edu.au/connect_with_acu/newsroom/news/media_releases/year/2016/the_funnier_you_are,_the_faster_you_die

Comment: I edited the title slightly to state more clearly what (in my opinion) is the question being asked.  Put back if you don't agree with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lindy effect. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindy_effect for more information.

Comment: +1 Note that this doesn't actually apply to the case you posit: it isn't mathematically possible for the conditional expectation always to *equal* the elapsed time.